# Dependency approach

Tags: c++, oop

Well i am making a PE loader on C++ (not my main lang) and i have the following classes:

```
//Main builder of PE file format
class PEC
{
   HMODULE mapTo(char* fullpath);
}

//Build the imports
class ImportBuilder
{
    //This func needs PEC::MapTo
    bool buildImports(HMODULE module) 
}

//Find the exports
class ExportFinder
{
   //This func needs PEC::MapTo
   void* findExport(int ordinal, HMODULE module);
}
```

The problem is PEC class needs ImportBuilder class for rebuild the imports, but also the ImportBuilder class needs the PEC class for loading module imports that are not founded inside the current process. The same goes for ExportBuilder, he needs the PEC::MapTo function for loading some forwarded export modules that are not founded.

This leads me to a cyclic dependency... any method to solve this?.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for forward declarations and pimpl idiom??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is basically one of indirect recursion.

You load a file. Then you try to resolve its imports.

To do that you (recursively) load more files, and attempt to resolve their imports.

You're done when you reach one of two points:

1. all the imports are satisfied, and the load is successful
2. you can't resolve an import, and the load fails

Two obvious possibilities that lead to the latter are that you can't find a file that's supposed to contain some symbols you need to resolve, or you do find the file, but it doesn't export a symbol it's supposed to resolve.

That really only changes the error message you print out though -- "unable to find foo.dll" vs. "foo.dll does not export required symbol bar()".

Rereading, perhaps you're just talking about how to resolve the circular dependency in your code. Typically you do this by rearranging the code to an order something like this:

```
class PEC;

class ImportBuilder { 
   // function declarations, but not definitions here
   // functions can use references or pointers to a PEC, but not
   //     actual PEC objects.
};

class PEC { 
    // function declarations, but not definitions here
};

// Definitions of member functions for PEC and ImportBuilder here
```

Comment: Thanks i already have everything coded related to PE header structure, the problem is C++ complains about re using the same headers on different headers. (Cyclic dependency)